# Removing quotes from JSON Rails 4 and JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to send a JSON API response from my rails app to Dasheroo which expects the following format:

```
{
  my_statistic: { type: 'integer', value: 1, label: 'My Statistic' }
}
```

However it is not happy with my data structure generated by the following code:

In controller:

```
def count_foo_members
    @foo = Foo.all.count
end
```

In count_foo_members.json.jbuilder:

```
json.foo_members do
    json.type  'integer'
    json.value @foo
    json.label 'Foo Members'
end
```

If I open this route in my browser I can see the following:

```
{
    "foo_members":{"type":"integer","value":1,"label":"Foo Members"}
}
```

From the results above, the only thing that I can see that could have an effect on the result is the fact that my JSON result has quotation marks around the JSON Key values.

My question thus is: How can I remove these quotation marks in Rails 4 and JBuilder?

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388635/remove-quotes-from-jbuilder-json, hope it will help you

Comment: That is how JSON works, JSON has only string, integers and null values. You can't remove quotes, otherwise it's will be not JSON

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(you_response) and you get standart hash.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the quotation marks from the keys. The responsibility is on the consumer (Dasheroo) to parse your JSON string into a JavaScript Object, which will "remove" the quotes from the keys.

Read [json-object-with-or-without-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635132/json-object-with-or-without-quotes) for further practical insight.